# Spring annotation value from configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jms, spring-annotations

In my Spring Boot application I have configured following JMS Listener:

```java
@Component
public class Consumer {
    
    @JmsListener(destination = "image.index.queue")
    public void receiveQueue(IndexRequest indexRequest) {
        ...
    }   
}
```

How to supply destination name `image.index.queue` from configuration (e.g. `application.properties`) instead of a hardcoded value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

@JmsListener(destination = @Value("${jmx.image.index.queue}")
public void receiveQueue(IndexRequest indexRequest) {
    ...
}
```

And in your properties file

```
jmx.image.index.queue=image.index.queue
```

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Value to String

Comment: following construction works: @JmsListener(destination = "${jmx.image.index.queue}")

Answer (score 1):

You need to indicate to Spring that it's a placeholder value, so instead of:

```java
@JmsListener(destination = "image.index.queue")
```

Use:

```java
@JmsListener(destination = "${image.index.queue}")
```

If needed, you can also use [SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html) but this shouldn't be necessary if using `application.properties`. E.g.:

```java
@JmsListener(destination = "#{systemProperties['image.index.queue']}")
```

Verified as of Spring Boot `2.0.0.RELEASE`